# Control buttosn in image slider don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an image slider. I am now creating the controll buttons like you see on the images below.
[image]

But the buttons don't work. if I click on the buttons nothing happens.

**this is the Jquery code for the two buttons**

```
//detect click next and for button
$('.Sbutton').on('click','#for',function(){
  var margin_next = (next * 800)-800;
  $('.img').animate({marginLeft:-margin_next},500);
  varr();
});
$('.Sbutton').on('click','#back',function(){
  var margin_prev =(prev * 800)-800;
  $('.img').animate({marginLeft:margin_prev},500);
  varr();
});
```

can somebody help me with fixing this?

Comment: Can you provide the html and have you debugged the click events (do the fire)?

Comment: @Vinc199789, did you wrap you code inside `$(function(){ /*to do here*/  })`

Comment: the click events are working and when i go to console no error appears. and @balzafin the 2 variables are defined somewhere else on the file but they work.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the code you provided. With this information we can't help you. Make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or at least provide the rest of the code involved, especially the hmtl.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you have not defined `next` and `prev`. I did a quick fork and gave those variables values and it works just fine.